# How to iterate on each line of a rdd which contains textFile

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do something like this

```
file = sc.textFile('mytextfile')

def myfunction(mystring):
 new_value = mystring
 for i in file.toLocalIterator()
  if i in mystring:
   new_value = i
 return new_value;

rdd_row = some_data_frame.map(lambda u: Row(myfunction(u.column_name)))
```

But I get this error

> It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers

Comment: It would be better if you explain what you are trying to achieve and then it would be possible to try to help with that as well.

Comment: I have a textfile which in fact is a black list, and I have a dataframe with a column that contains urls. I want to parse each url and check if it's in the blacklist. If it is I will replace the value, otherwise I will keep the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (as is clearly stated in the error message) that you are trying to work with an RDD inside the map. File is an RDD. it can have various transformations on it (e.g. you are trying to do a local iterator on it). But you are trying to use the transformation inside another - the map.

**UPDATE**

If I understand correctly you have a dataframe df with a column URL. You also have a text file which contains blacklist values.
Lets assume for the sake of argument that your blacklist files is a csv with a column blacklistNames and that the dataframe df's URL column is already parsed. i.e. you just want to check if URL is in the blacklistNames columns.

What you can do is something like this:

```
df.join(blackListDF, df["URL"]==blackListDF["blacklistNames"], "left_outer")
```

This join basically adds a blacklistNames column to your original dataframe which would contain the matched name if it is in the blacklist and null otherwise. Now all you need to do is filter based on whether or not the new column is null or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah I understand it, so my question is, there is another  way to do it? I can put each element of my texfile in a list and iterate on it, but It will take to much time to process, because I have like one millions urls to check and there is 85000 elements in the textfile

Comment: Yeah, that's a great idea, but the thing is, with a join you compare if both values are strictly equal, and I want to check if the url value contains the values from the blacklist. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Then I would suggest you use an external program to turn the blacklist into some text analyzer and then use map for it. For example use aho-corasick or similar algorithm for the testing. Take the 850K elements, generate a trie from a subset which can fit in memory of a single executor and continue to do the same until you cover everything. Then run multiple filters where each time you test the relevant subset.